# If a character casts a spell requiring concentration, do they know when it is no longer doing anything?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

A cleric casts *[bane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane)* on 3 orcs.  Two make their saving throw.  RAW, the cleric does not know which orc was affected.

The fighter rushes over and kills the orc that was affected by the *bane*, but the other two are still alive.

Does the cleric realize that concentration is no longer relevant because there are no more creature being affected?